# How to increase size of canvas image in html

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have taken 2 canvas one is the source and another is ther target. When I mouse over the image in canvas it should get enlarged in canvas2
How can I increase the height of image in canvas2 i want magnify effect .Below is the code.

Thanks
Husein

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="h()">
<p>Image to use:</p>


<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" onmousemove="h()" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<p>Canvas2:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin="anonymous";
image.src="img_the_scream.jpg" 

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=image ;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var d=document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx1=d.getContext("2d");



function h()
{
var img=ctx.getImageData(event.clientX-80,event.clientY-100,100,100);
ctx1.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , d.width , d.height );
ctx1.putImageData(img,0,0);

//d.width="200";
//d.height="200";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use toDataUrl and drawImage instead of getImageData and putImageData. Example:

```
function h() {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src = ctx.toDataUrl();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0,c.width*horizontalMagnification,c.height*verticalMagnification);
    };
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could just call `ctx1.scale(horizontalMagnification,verticalMagnification);` before you use putImageData.